# Why does List.Add() return an index error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, my C# script gives the following error message on the sortOrderList.Add() line:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
> the collection.

Here is the structure of the database I'm sorting.

[image]

What the part of the script below is doing is making a list of index locations for each of the types that can be found at varying locations based on their load order.  List sortOrderList shows the order to load each of the the types in, where a for loop could iterate from 0 to sortOrderList.Count - 1 to account for all the different types in all the categories combined and access these later on in the script below.

For instance, if the following are locations of different types which each have a varying method: List {type1 1, type2 2, type2 3, type1 4, type1 5, type2 6}, then where type2 loads first, sortOrderList is {2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5}. type1 and type2 are to represent methods defined in the script below.

```
foreach (DataClasses.DependencyMethodEnum method in dataClasses.DependencyMethodOrder)//for order of dependencies; add SortOrderList after the localTypeNames have been completely filled
    {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < categoryNames.Count; i1++)//for each category i1
        {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < listsTypeNames[i1].Count; i2++)//for each type i2
            {
                if (listsTypeMethods[i1][i2] == method)//if the dependency order aligns with the current type
                {
                    int iterations = 0;
                    bool breaking = false;

                    for (int i4 = 0; i4 < categoryNames.Count; i4++)//again for each category i4; this is to sort out where the original order would be on the main list Lists//IS INEFFECTIVE: CALLS THE SAME ONE INSIDE EACH CATEGORY
                    {
                        for (int i5 = 0; i5 < listsTypeNames[i4].Count; i5++)//for each type i5
                        {
                            Debug.Log(localTypeNames.Count);//high number....
                            Debug.Log(sortOrderList.Count);//0... so why is there an error when I later use .Add?

                            if (listsTypeNames[i4][i5] == listsTypeNames[i1][i2] && (sortOrderList.Count == 0 || (sortOrderList.Count != 0 && listsTypeNames[i4][i5] != localTypeNames[sortOrderList[sortOrderList.Count - 1]])))
                            {
                                Debug.Log("PASS");
                                Debug.Log("ITERATIONS:" + iterations);
                                Debug.Log("SOL COUNT: " + sortOrderList.Count);

                                sortOrderList.Add(iterations);//adds where the original position would have been for the type in the order of where it is in the local list//ERROR HERE

                                Debug.Log("sol " + sortOrderList.Count + " : " + localTypeNames[sortOrderList[iterations]]);
                                breaking = true;
                                break;
                            }

                            iterations++;
                        }

                        if (breaking)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Why does this happen?  I'm not addressing a specific index on the sortOrderList.Add() layer, but it still gives the error.  Here's the log.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use indexes into your containers, just use `foreach` instead.

Comment: What's the type of `sortOrderList`? The overload you're calling doesn't specify the insert index - is `SortList` being called from multiple threads?

Comment: Seems you only access the list twice - once if the count is not zero to get the last element, and once in a `Debug.Log` statement.  Which of those is line 161 from your stack trace?  Or is it really the call to .Add that is throwing the exception?

Comment: Don't understand what exactly you are sorting on but I guess you would be way better simply using [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) for filtering and then for sorting [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) and [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby) or the according *descending* versions ...

Comment: @CJohnson Thanks for the advice, but I need to access indexes elsewhere in the script.

Comment: @Lee sortOrderList is a List<int> calling!

Comment: @SeanSkelly Line 161 is the final bracket shown in the code I linked above, meaning the error was somewhere within the function.  Using debugs, I was able to trace it to the line: sortOrderList.Add(iterations);.  I access this list many times outside of this function after it's set.

Comment: @derHugo I restructured my code so it's easier to follow, and looked into using Linq functions.  Although I'm very glad you made me aware that these exist for future coding, what it's doing is making a list of the index each of the types can be found at varying on their load order.  For instance, List<int> {type1 1, type2 2, type2 3, type1 4, type1 5, type2 6} where type2 loads first = sortOrderList {2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5}.  type1 and type2 are to represent methods defined in the script above.  I don't think I can use Linq for this, but thanks for the suggestion, and I'm open to any alternatives!

Answer (score 0):

Someone pointed out that

> Debug.Log("sol " + sortOrderList.Count + " : " + localTypeNames[sortOrderList[iterations]]);

is actually the real source of the problem, since when sortOrderList.Count = 1 and it's searching for an iteration way later on, it returns an index error.  Thanks to all for the help!  If the person responds on StackOverflow, I'll mark their answer correct.